# String reverse in Python

Tags: python

Write a simple program that reads a line from the keyboard and outputs the same line where
every word is reversed. A word is defined as a continuous sequence of alphanumeric characters
or hyphen (‘-’). For instance, if the input is
“Can you help me!”
the output should be
“naC uoy pleh em!”

I just tryed with the following code, but there are some problem with it,

```
print"Enter the string:"
str1=raw_input()
print (' '.join((str1[::-1]).split(' ')[::-2]))
```

It prints "naC uoy pleh !em", just look the exclamation(!), it is the problem here. Anybody can help me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to find each word and reverse it:

```
In [8]: import re

In [9]: s = "Can you help me!"

In [10]: re.sub(r'[-\w]+', lambda w:w.group()[::-1], s)
Out[10]: 'naC uoy pleh em!'
```

Comment: that's a nice way, in my opinion.

Comment: Note that ``\w`` symbolizes alphanumeric **and underscore** while OP didn't defined a word as possibly containing an underscore

Answer (score 6):

The easiest is probably to use the `re` module to split the string:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(\W)')
string = raw_input('Enter the string: ')
print ''.join(x[::-1] for x in pattern.split(string))
```

When run, you get:

```
Enter the string: Can you help me!
naC uoy pleh em!
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly on string containing hyphens. I think the pattern should be changed to re.compile('([^\w\-])')

Comment: ``(\W+)`` would be better than ``(\W)`` - Note that \W symbolizes other characters than alphanumeric ones and underscore while OP didn't defined a word as possibly containing an underscore

Answer (score 0):

My answer, more verbose though. It handles more than one punctuation mark at the end as well as punctuation marks within the sentence.

```
import string
import re

valid_punctuation = string.punctuation.replace('-', '')
word_pattern = re.compile(r'([\w|-]+)([' + valid_punctuation + ']*)$')

# reverses word. ignores punctuation at the end.
# assumes a single word (i.e. no spaces)
def word_reverse(w):
    m = re.match(word_pattern, w)
    return ''.join(reversed(m.groups(1)[0])) + m.groups(1)[1]

def sentence_reverse(s):
    return ' '.join([word_reverse(w) for w in re.split(r'\s+', s)])

str1 = raw_input('Enter the sentence: ')
print sentence_reverse(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without using `re` module:

```
print 'Enter the string:'
string = raw_input()

line = word = ''

for char in string:
    if char.isalnum() or char == '-':
        word = char + word
    else:
        if word:
            line += word
            word = ''
        line += char

print line + word
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this.

```
print"Enter the string:"

str1=raw_input()

print( ' '.join(str1[::-1].split(' ')[::-1]) )
```

or then, this

```
print(' '.join([w[::-1] for w in a.split(' ') ]))
```

Comment: the output would be exactly like what OP already has: "naC uoy pleh !em".